# Adding up inputs doesn't change javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add up 3 input  elements of type number. This doesn't work for some reason. When I take out the if statements, it works, but only after I change the first one (score1). When I change the others, nothing happens. Thanks.

```
function getTotal() {

var score1 = document.getElementById("score1");
var score2 = document.getElementById("score2");
var score3 = document.getElementById("score3");

var sc1 = parseInt(score1.value);
var sc2 = parseInt(score2.value);
var sc3 = parseInt(score3.value);

if (isNan(sc1)) {
    sc1 = 0;
}

if (isNan(sc2)) {
    sc2 = 0;
}

if (isNan(sc3)) {
    sc3 = 0;
}

var total = sc1 + sc2 + sc3;
document.getElementById("totalScore").innerHTML = total;

}

function assign() {
    var score1 = document.getElementbyId("score1");
    var score2 = document.getElementbyId("score2");
    var score3 = document.getElementbyId("score3");    

    score1.onchange = getTotal;
    score2.onchange = getTotal;
    score3.onchange = getTotal;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="getTotal.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Total: 
            <output id="total" class="totalScore"></output>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </header>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <td>Score 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="score1"/></td>

      <td>Score 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="score2" /></td>

      <td>Score 3</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="score3" /></td>
    </tbody>
  </table>

   <script type="text/javascript">assign();</script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Spelling mistake.

```
var score1 = document.getElementbyId("score1");
var score2 = document.getElementbyId("score2");
var score3 = document.getElementbyId("score3");
```

If you check your console you will see the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line where you are calling score1. The selector is `document.getElement*By*Id`, you were writing `by` lowercase..

Answer (score 0):

Your `<output>` has an id attribute with the value is "total" whereas your class attribute' value is "totalscore". Consider changing the id value to "totalscore" or change getElementById's value to"score"